# Locust : HTTPConnectionClosed

Tags: python, docker, flask, kubernetes, locust

I am using locust for load testing, I have deployed locust in kubernetes with master and workers. I am testing with 100 users and Hatch rate 20 users. After certain requests, I am continuously facing the issue with 'HttpConnectionClosed'. I have researched lot on this but none of them given me clue.

[image]

I really appreciate if anyone help me.

Comment: Are you running inside container?

Comment: yes, that correct

Comment: That's interesting, did you tried restarting the container?

Comment: yes I have tried that as well, generally what would be the reason behind that issue?

Answer (score 0):

This means that the HTTP server unexpectedly closed or reset the connection before Locust received the HTTP headers (or possibly some network element between Locust and the server interrupted the connection)

The source is here: https://github.com/gwik/geventhttpclient/blob/aea7c3a61fd9c88159f6f929888879705faecc25/src/geventhttpclient/response.py#L195

You might want to try the regular HttpUser instead of FastHttpUser to see if there is some subtle difference (or maybe a more clear error message), but this is most likely a "real" issue, not a Locust problem.

Comment: That's right , I am using FastHttpUser, let t mec check

Comment: I am experiencing connection reset issue in kubernetes, is it this is relates kubernetes and not locust?